# Using a boolean attribute as a conditional on an update action on a model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, before-filter

Imagine I have a boolean and a string attribute on my model with data like this:

```
Model.locked => true
Model.status => "Available"
```

When the Update action is invoked, I want to use the boolean attribute to control whether the string attribute gets modified by the update, all other attributes in the update should be saved regardless.

So if

```
Model.locked => true
```

and we try

```
Model.status = "Sold"
```

then

```
Model.status => "Available"
```

Currently I have my model like this...

```
before_update :dont_update_locked_item, :if => :item_locked?

def item_locked?
  self.locked
end

def dont_update_locked_item
  #Some rails magic goes here
end
```

How do I prevent a single attribute from being updated?

I know the answer is going to hurt, but someone help me out. It's late, I'm tired and I'm fresh out of talent. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it doesn't hurt so much :)

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :cannot_update_if_locked, :on => :update

  def item_locked?
    self.locked
  end

  def cannot_update_if_locked
    errors.add(:item_id, "is locked") if item_locked?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer negarni, this is close, but doesn't allow the rest of the attributes being set to be committed. I need just that one locked attribute to be excluded from the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Item < ActiveReocrd::Base

  def mass_assignment_authorizer
    super + (locked? ? [] : [:status])
  end
end
```

Reference:

[Dynamic attr_accessible](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible)

Comment: Unfortunately this still allows the attribute to be updated even when locked? returns true. Do I need to add anything to the update action in the controller?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Sorry I should had mentioned that in my question, ruby 1.9.3p236, rails 3.2.6